# Python - Reshape not working

Tags: python, neural-network, theano, deep-learning, keras

I am using `keras` to train a CNN and the base error is dimensionality mismatch.

Reason, after debugging is:

```
print("Before")
print(TX.shape)
print(TeX.shape)

X_train = TX.reshape(1000, 1, img_rows, img_cols)
X_test = TeX.reshape(430, 1, img_rows, img_cols)
print("After")
print(TX.shape)
print(TeX.shape)
```

Generating the output:

```
Using Theano backend.
Using gpu device 0: GeForce GTX 750 Ti (CNMeM is disabled, CuDNN not available)
Before
(1000, 27, 36)
(430, 27, 36)
After
(1000, 27, 36)
(430, 27, 36)
```

If needed, my model's summary is:

```
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

## Layer (type)                       Output Shape        Param #     Connected to

convolution2d_1 (Convolution2D)    (None, 32, 25, 34)  320         convolution2d_input_1[0][0]

---

activation_1 (Activation)          (None, 32, 25, 34)  0           convolution2d_1[0][0]

---

convolution2d_2 (Convolution2D)    (None, 32, 23, 32)  9248        activation_1[0][0]

---

activation_2 (Activation)          (None, 32, 23, 32)  0           convolution2d_2[0][0]

---

convolution2d_3 (Convolution2D)    (None, 32, 21, 30)  9248        activation_2[0][0]

---

activation_3 (Activation)          (None, 32, 21, 30)  0           convolution2d_3[0][0]

---

maxpooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2D)      (None, 32, 10, 15)  0           activation_3[0][0]

---

dropout_1 (Dropout)                (None, 32, 10, 15)  0           maxpooling2d_1[0][0]

---

flatten_1 (Flatten)                (None, 4800)        0           dropout_1[0][0]

---

dense_1 (Dense)                    (None, 128)         614528      flatten_1[0][0]

---

activation_4 (Activation)          (None, 128)         0           dense_1[0][0]

---

dropout_2 (Dropout)                (None, 128)         0           activation_4[0][0]

---

dense_2 (Dense)                    (None, 26)          3354        dropout_2[0][0]

---

## activation_5 (Activation)          (None, 26)          0           dense_2[0][0]

Total params: 636698

---

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are assigning the reshaped arrays to a new variable, but then you are still printing the shape of the old variable:

```
X_train = TX.reshape(..)
```

You must use:

```
print(X_train.shape)
```

Comment: hello @Cyb3rFly3r, I assigned a reshaped array (in numpy) to a new variable, and I was able to get the new array in a new shape.  But isn't it supposed to work on the  array ('a') itself, when you use it like this?  : a.reshape(x,y)

Comment: Yes, a.reshape(x,y).shape should give you (x,y) as the new shape, as long as the dimensions are consistent with the number of elements.